# ASP.NET - Overwritten log file

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have an ASP.NET application.  Every time I use the 'Publish Web Site' option in Visual Studio, the permissions to the log file on (/logs/log.log) are overwritten on the server and NETWORK SERVICE no longer has access.

I have tried changing the permissions in IIS i.e. right click on the folder in IIS and select permissions, however the permissions still revert back.  How do you change the permissions permanently?

Comment: Change the permission on the Directory `/logs/` and the log.log will take them. But if the log.log is copy over on the publish then must stop that copy.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to write a batch file that is run every time there is an update.